# How to access data from two different table within single model/controller/form in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am a new and beginner in yii, so i am asking that question.

Actually I have two different tables.

**First is Language.**

In there are two fields language(id, language_name) // here id is primary key.

**Second is Scholar.**

Scholar has 6 fields. Scholar(id, name, language_id, contact_no, country, email) //here id is primary key and whereas language_id is foreign key references to language.

Now Through Gii Code Generator i have generated model, controller and view with form generator of Language and Scholar, where i can add different languages and scholar too and i can manage it.

**Now my question is When I click on manage scholars, it will show language id and i want to display here language name.**

So can you help me how i can access here language name instead of language id.

I can get language name by below code written in view file.

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('language_id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria ;
        $criteria->select='language_name';
        $qAlbums=Language::model()->findbyPk($data->language_id);
        echo $qAlbums->language_name;
    ?>
```

but I do not want to write such like of code in view, i want that, i get data directly like `$data->language_name` that comes in array.

Thanks

Comment: It is given in detail in the official docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query , basically you have to use relations to pull in related tables using `with`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your `Scholar` class has a relation called `language` defined as follows in your model's `relations()` method:

```
'language' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Language', 'language_id'),
```

You can now use `<?php echo $data->language->language_name; ?>` in your views and `language.language_name` as field name for CDetailViews and CGridViews.

Comment: You can also add a __toString() method to the  Language model. So the code shortens down to this <?php echo $data->language; ?>